# how to append multiple rows of data frame against unique ID in Ipython

Tags: pandas, ipython

I have a data frame with three columns {PatientID, Name, Description}. The records in data frame are of the following form i.e. multiple descriptions against same patientID and name.
[image: Patient Data frame]

I want to find frequently used word in the description. The output should be of the following form
[image]

I am using following code in Ipython

```
for index, record in patientdf.iterrows():
    freqs = Counter(record['Description'].split())
    print freqs.most_common(1)
```

This is giving me frequent used word of description column of each row. I want frequent used word against unique ID of patient. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
u = df.groupby("PatientID")
list123 = []
list111 = []
p = u.last()
for i in u:
    list111.append(i[1].Description.sum())

u["text"] = list111

for i in q.text:
    freqs = Counter(i.split())
    print freqs.most_common(1)
    list123.append(freqs.most_common(1)[0][0])

p["Frequent word"] = list123
```

This should work

Comment: What's para2 in this line? u.Description.sum().para2.split()

Comment: sorry there should be ur patient id ...in my case it was para id so by mistake i put para2

Comment: I am getting assignment error: TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment

Comment: you shouldnt get this error ... as I suggestend in ans the assignment is done on p which is p = u.last() ..(not a groupby ele)

Comment: can u please pass me directery or list to reproduce dataframe ...(really felng lazy to reproduce from image)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was myself doing some syntax error. Can you also please tell me how to query data frame 'p' to get value of "Frequent Word" and "Name" column against PatientID. I tried this but giving error: p['abc1']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106077/discussion-between-sam-p-and-dark-matter).

Comment: p['frequent_word'].patient_id